# как правильно работать с pfx файлом(получаю ошибку pkcs12: unknown digest algorithm: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1)

Tags: golang

пакет "golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12"

```
//читаю файл
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("PFXfile")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err, nil
    }

//здесь ошибка
    blocks, err := pkcs12.ToPEM(data, "Password")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
//pkcs12: unknown digest algorithm: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1
```

Comment: видимо проблема в PFXfile файле

Comment: что-то не так это верно, но при этом через postman - всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: непонятно что конкретно делаете через postman. если есть возможность, то лучше приложить PFXfile

Comment: серьёзно? приложить сертификат ))) Жесть.....

Comment: шалость не удалась